# Segfault when calling a virtual function in another DLL

Tags: c++, windows, dll

I have a two-part program where the main core needs to have an adapter registered and then call back into the register. The parts are in separate DLLs, and the core doesn't know the adapter's specifics (besides methods and parameters ahead of time). I've tried setting it up with the following code and recieve a segfault every time the core tries to call an adapter method:

*Core.hpp/cpp (combined and simplified)*:

```
class Core
{
public:
    Core()
        : mAdapter(NULL)
    { }

    void DoStuff(int param)
    {
        if ( this->mAdapter )
        {
            this->mAdapter->Prepare(param);
        }
    }

    void Register(Adapter * adapter)
    {
        this->mAdapter = adapter;
    }

private:
    Adapter * mAdapter;
};
```

*Adapter.hpp/cpp (in the core library)*:

```
class Adapter
{
public:
    Adapter(Core * core) { }

    virtual void Prepare(int param)
    {
        // For testing, this is defined here
        throw("Non-overridden adapter function called.");
    }
};
```

*AdapterSpecific.hpp/cpp (second library)*:

```
class Adapter_Specific
    : Adapter
{
public:
    Adapter_Specific(Core * core)
    {
        core->Register(this);
    }

    void Prepare(int param) { ... }
};
```

All classes and methods are marked as DLL export while building the first module (core) and the core is marked as export, the adapter as import while building the adapter.

The code runs fine up until the point where Core::DoStuff is called. From walking through the assembly, it appears that it resolves the function from the vftable, but the address it ends up with is an 0x0013nnnn, and my modules are in the 0x0084nnnn and above range. Visual Studio's source debugger and the intellisense shows the the entries in the vftable are the same and the appropriate one does go to a very low address (one also goes to 0xF-something, which seems equally odd).

*Edit for clarity*: Execution never re-enters the adapter_specific class or module. The supposed address for the call is invalid and execution gets lost there, resulting in the segfault. It's not an issue with any code in the adapter class, which is why I left that out.

I've rebuilt both libraries more than once, in debug mode. This is pure C++, nothing fancy. I'm not sure why it won't work, but I need to call back into the other class and would rather avoid using a struct of function ptrs.

Is there a way to use neat callbacks like this between modules or is it somehow impossible?

Comment: Why are people cluttering the code with "this->"?

Comment: This isn't the actual code, just the applicable parts slightly reworded (structure is unchanged). Those are in some parts of the actual code where it could be misread though.

Comment: @VJo: explicit is always better than implicit

Comment: Why is `Adapter_Specific` not derived from `Adapter`? Is this just copy/paste error? Also, where are your virtual destructors?

Comment: is Adapter_Specific supposed to implement Adapter?  right now it's not... also do you mean core->Register instead of core->SetAdapter?

Comment: @Nikolai: yes, that was a typo, fixed. The complete code isn't there, just what was needed for the error (there are far more methods in each class, etc).

Comment: I am failing miserably at copy/pasting and typing today. xD I think I got most of the typos. The original code compiles fine, no warning at level 4.

Comment: @Falmarri:  A reasonable variable-naming scheme is better than using `this->`

Comment: @John: Why make your own naming scheme when `this->` serves as perfect documentation.

Comment: @Falmarri:  Because it doesn't serve as perfect *documentation when you (or someone else) forget to put the `this->`

Comment: @Falmari: Plus typing `_` is fewer keystrokes than typing `this->`, and it doesn't kick intellisense in to gear when you don't want intellisense

Comment: Forgetting to put the documentation doesn't make it any less valid. And the number of keystrokes and IDE issues sound like personal problems with your IDE, not with the use of `this->`

Comment: Putting `this->` in front of every member access just screams "I don't understand C++ name lookup rules".  It also hides the cases where `this->` IS required (generally when accessing members of a base class which is a template parameter).

Comment: Heh, funny debate this started (no pun intended). The occurrences of  `this->` in the snippets above is purely for SO's sake to make things absolutely unambiguous (hopefully). I'm of the opinion that, while not always necessary, it does provide convenient at-a-glance documentation and works nicely for triggering intellisense when needed (although, I use visual assist, so that's a non-issue anymore).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being a stupid mistake on my part.

In another function in the code, I was accidentally feeding a function a `Core *` instead of the `Adapter *` and didn't catch it in my read-through. Somehow the compiler didn't catch it either (it should have failed, but no implicit cast warning was given, possibly because it was a reference-counted point).

That tried to turn the `Core *` into an Adapter and get the vftable from that mutant object, which failed miserably and resulted in a segfault. I fixed it to be the proper type and all works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You said all your methods are declared DLL exports. Methods (member functions) do not have to be marked that way ,exporting the class is sufficient. I don't know if it's harmfull if you do.

Comment: I had the methods without the export keyword and VS put out some warnings, if I remember right. It doesn't seem to change the behavior.

Comment: @peachykeen: Strange ,it's really not necessary (just tested it to be sure).

Comment: @peachykeen: Even got errors when using it on member (member of dll interface class may not be declared with dll interface) . So I think were not talking of the same thing.

Comment: @peachykeen: I remove dllexport from the class and placed it on the members ,now it will build.

Comment: @peachykeen: This leeds me to think the following. Because you have made you members dllexports but not the class ,your member data is in a different memory-area than your code (maybe not the correct terminology ,but I hope you understand it). Just try __declspec(dllexport) CLASSNAME ,and remove __declspec(dllexport) from your member-functions and rebuild everything.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are using a lot of pointers. Where are their lifetimes managed?
2. Adapter_Specific is inheriting private from Adapter in your example
3. Adapter has a virtual method so probably needs a virtual destructor too
4. Adapter also has no default constructor so the constructor of Adapter_Specific won't compile. You might want it to construct the base class with the same parameter. This does not happen automatically. However see point 6.
5. Constructors that take exactly one parameter (other than the copy constructor) should normally be declared explicit.
6. The base class Adapter takes a parameter it does not use.

Answer (score 0):

`__declspec(dllexport)` on classes and class members is a really bad idea.  It's much better to use an interface (base class containing only virtual functions, it's essentially the same as the "struct of function pointers" you didn't want, except the compiler handles all the details), and use `__declspec(dllexport)` only for global functions such as factory functions.  Especially don't call constructors and destructors directly across DLL boundaries because you'll get mismatched allocators, expose an ordinary function which wraps the special functions.

Comment: Originally the `__declspec(dllexport)` was only on the classes (`class EXPORT Core`), but I expanded it just to make sure that wasn't the issue (turned out not to be). My current working solution does have an interface as the basis, although at one point I call a constructor across a DLL. This happens rarely and would be possible to avoid; is it a significant issue/risk? Most things are reference-counted pointers, those wouldn't cause any similar errors, would they?

Comment: The safest way to definitely to follow the COM rules for `IUnknown`.  It's reference counted pointers, but the object is responsible for maintaining its reference count, which means the final destructor call always comes from inside the DLL where the object is implemented.  On the other hand with your typical C++ smart pointer,  the code for adjusting the reference count and calling the deallocator is inlined all over the place, which means the class layout has to match exactly, allocator has to be shared, which is just really fragile.

Comment: You can easily end up unable to ever move to a newer compiler version, because one of your libraries has included code from one particular version of the runtime library and calls it for objects it gets from other modules.